# Django: store common fields in a parent model

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I've got some models:

```python
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)

class Bar(Place):
    drinks = models.ManyToManyField('Drink')

class Restaurant(Place):
    meals = models.ManyToManyField('Meals')
```

That's a multi-table inherited structure where each bar serves drinks only, and each restaurant serves meals only. I, though, need a name of each place to be unique across all the places - hence the parent `Place` model.

Now, multi-table inheritance presumes a parent and a child are separate entities. That means when I want to create a new `Bar`, I should go like this:

```
>> parent = Place(name='Myplace')
>> parent.save()
>> child = Bar(place=parent, drinks=mydrinklist)
>> child.save()
```

But in my case, `Place` is not a separate entity: it should not exists by itself. It's just a shared storage with some restrictions. I'd like to have something like this:

```
>> child = Bar(name='Myplace', drinks=mydrinklist)
>> child.save()
```

Where `name` attribute is automatically passed to the underlying parent model and a `Place` model is silently created when `save()` is called. SQLAlchemy can do that via its multi-table inheritance. Is there a way to achieve the same in Django?

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `Place.save` method and implementing the logic you're describing there?

Comment: Did you try your suggested syntax? This is exactly how multi-table inheritance works in Django, and your desired syntax works correctly with the models you've shown. (In fact, your first version *wouldn't* work, because `parent` is not a field on Bar.)

Comment: Wow, that actually works. I've faced some error with the `name` field in django-rest-framework and thought that was associated with incorrect `save` call; looks like I was wrong. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Django's [abstract base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) solve the problem of sharing common fields between models:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

**Edit**: Having said that, as Daniel mentioned in the comments, the solution you propose should work just fine. Here's more on [Django's multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)

Comment: But what about global `unique` constraint? Isn't `name` now supposed to be stored in `bar` and `restaurant` tables separately?