# How to make Model's PK as FK to all Django's Project Models

Tags: django, django-models

I need some help to figure out what's the best way to design following model use case in Django.

I have model "Client" which defines client id for an app. This model needs to refer as a foreign key to all models of project.

Here is code snippet:

```
Class Client(Model):
    ClientId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

Class Location(Model):
    LocationId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ClientId = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="ClientId")

Class User(Model):
    UserId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ClientId = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="ClientId")

Class Document(Model):
    DocumentId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ClientId = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column="ClientId")
```

As shown above, Location, User and Document all have ClientId as FK.
It works however....

Issue with above design is that I have to explicitly specify ClientId as FK in each table. As ClientID is required FK for each models of Project, I want to know if there is any simple design pattern where ClientId is defined as FK to each model without specifying it.

I have thought of using inheritance but that does not work as there is only one Global ClientId and defining Client as Parent for each model means it creates Client Id each time new instance of child is created.

Any idea or pointer to this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: store common fields in a parent model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21304025/django-store-common-fields-in-a-parent-model)

Comment: You should make use of abstract classes as indicated in the answer shared by @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried Abstract Class as well but that does not work since ClientID has to be unique for all models within the APP/Project.  If I create Abstract class then each row will define clientid for each of models of Location. Document, user etc...

Client representing Multi tanent client and each models are unique to this client.  So ClientId has to presented in each models of App to ensure there is explicit assignment for design.  

I hope this further clarify the use case.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with an *abstract base model*. The only problem here might be that the [**`related_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) and [**`related_query_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) can clash, so you can specify this with:

```
from django.db import models


class Client(models.Model):
    client_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)


class ClientRelatedModel(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(
        Client,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_column='ClientId',
        related_name='%(class)s_set',
        related_query_name='%(class)s',
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Location(ClientRelatedModel):
    location_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)


class Document(ClientRelatedModel):
    document_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `client_id` instead of <s>`clientId`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `…_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `…_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `client`, instead of <s>`clientId`</s>.

Comment: Sir Willem I've seen a lot of times, you share development version docs, is there any reason for that? (Maybe you use that only :-) )

Comment: Thanks @Willem Van Onsem.  Very userful tip.  let me test out the solution.   What's the Django naming convention for join tables.  Example Join table of Location and User should be LocationUser so how should I define this table?  Thank You.

Comment: @SunderamDubey maybe because the dev link always points to the development version so the link doesn't go stale and point to outdated versions? Fun fact: You can replace the "dev" or the version with "stable" and you'll get redirected to the docs for the latest stable version.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yes you're right and I also know that fun fact :) but I was asking since I assumed it's different, haven't used yet.