# How to make Model Save method the PK gets incremented by n number

Tags: django, django-models

This is follow up question to my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74434588/how-to-make-models-pk-as-fk-to-all-djangos-project-models).

I am trying to overwrite the Save method of model so that the primary key gets incremented by 5 as follow:

```
class Client(Model):
    client_id= models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

    
    # Overwrite the Save functionality to increment the Client ID by 5
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            if self._state.adding is True:
                # Intialize the first Client Id to 5 and then after Increment by 5
                if not Client.object.count():
                    self.client_id = 5
                else:
                    self.client = Client.object.last().client_id + 5
                super(Client, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        except (Exception, FileNotFoundError, IOError, ValueError) as e:
            print(e)
            return False
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.client_name)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Client'
```

However, the above code is not working infact its not creating client entry at all.

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

In the else part you are not assigning **client_id**. Add the following code :

```
if not Client.object.count():
    self.client_id = 5
else:
    self.client_id = Client.object.last().client_id + 5
```